# How can I sanitize my DB from these duplicates

Tags: mysql

I have a table with the following fields:
id | domainname | domain_certificate_no | keyvalue

An example for the output of a select statement can be as:

```
'57092', '02a1fae.netsolstores.com', '02a1fae.netsolstores.com_1', '55525772666'
'57093', '02a1fae.netsolstores.com', '02a1fae.netsolstores.com_2', '22225554186'
'57094', '02a1fae.netsolstores.com', '02a1fae.netsolstores.com_3', '22444356259'
'97168', '02aa6aa.netsolstores.com', '02aa6aa.netsolstores.com_1', '55525772666'
'97169', '02aa6aa.netsolstores.com', '02aa6aa.netsolstores.com_2', '22225554186'
'97170', '02aa6aa.netsolstores.com', '02aa6aa.netsolstores.com_3', '22444356259’
```

I need to sanitize my db such that: I want to remove the domain names that have repeated `keyvalue` for the first `domain_certificate_no` (i.e, in this example, I look for the field `domain_certificate_no`: `02aa6aa.netsolstores.com_1`, since it is number 1, and has repeated value for the key, then I want to remove the whole chain which is `02aa6aa.netsolstores.com_2` and `02aa6aa.netsolstores.com_3` and this by deleting the domain name that this chain belongs to which is `02aa6aa.netsolstores.com`.

How can I automate the checking process for the whole DB. So, I have a query that checks any domain name in the pattern `('%.%.%)` **EDIT:** AND they have share domain name (in this ex: `netsolstores.com`) , if it finds cert no. 1 that belongs to this domain name has a repeated key value, then delete. Otherwise no. Please, note tat, it is ok for `domain_certificate_no` to have repeated value if it is not number 1.

**EDIT:** I only compare the repeated valeues for the same second level domain name. Ex: in this question, I compare the values that share the domain name:  `.netsolstores.com`. If I have another domain name, with sublevel domains, I do the same. But the point is that I don't need to compare the whole DB. Only the values with shared domain name (but different sub domain).

Comment: Can you clarify on the "deleting the chain" bit. If you're going to delete `02aa6aa.netsolstores.com` to delete the chain, what are you keeping? Are there cases where you do want the `_2` etc.?

Comment: In this example, if I deleted: `02a1fae.netsolstores.com`, I will keep the other domain `02aa6aa.netsolstores.com`. In other words, I don't need the whole chain if cert no. 1 have repeated key. There are no cases where I will need _2 if _1 deleted.

Comment: But bear in mind the edit I added. The comparison is betweent he domain names that have shared domin name but different sub level domain. i.e, if there are duplication with a different domain name say, `02a1fae.msn.com`, then it is fine. no need at all to compare with other domain names.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what happens with '02aa6aa.netsolstores.com_1' in your example.

The following keeps only the minimum id for any repeated key:

```
with t as (
     select t.*,
            substr(domain_certificate_no,
                   instr(domain_certificate_no, '_') + 1, 1000) as version,
            left(domain_certificate_no, instr(domain_certificate_no, '_') - 1) as dcn
     from t
    )
select t.*
from t join
     (select keyvalue, min(dcn) as mindcn
      from t
      group by keyvalue
     ) tsum
     on t.keyvalue = tsum.keyvalue and
        t.dcn = tsum.mindcn
```

For the data you provide, this seems to do the trick.  This will not return the "_1" version of the repeats.  If that is important, the query can be pretty easily modified.

Although I prefer to be more positive (thinking about the rows to keep rather than delete), the following should delete what you want:

```
with t as (
     select t.*,
            substr(domain_certificate_no,
                   instr(domain_certificate_no, '_') + 1, 1000) as version,
            left(domain_certificate_no, instr(domain_certificate_no, '_') - 1) as dcn
     from t
    ),
    tokeep as (
     select t.*
     from t join
          (select keyvalue, min(dcn) as mindcn
           from t
           group by keyvalue
          ) tsum
          on t.keyvalue = tsum.keyvalue and
             t.dcn = tsum.mindcn
    )
delete from t
where t.id not in (select id from tokeep)
```

There are other ways to express this that are possibly more efficient (depending on the database).  This, though, keeps the structure of the original query.

By the way, when trying new DELETE code, be sure that you stash a copy of the table.  It is easy to make a mistake with DELETE (and UPDATE).  For instance, if you leave out the WHERE clause, all the rows will disappear, after the long painful process of logging all of them.  You might find it faster to simply select the desired results into a new table, validate them, then truncate the old table and re-insert them.

Comment: It seems to me this is a select statement. I need to delete the repeated values. In general, when I try to delete records resulted from a query (in workbench), it does not allow me. It mark it with read only.

Comment: I don;t think so. I don't need to keep the minimum for any repeated key. I want to keep the minimum for any repeated key for the domain names that share the domain name (in my example, the shared domain name is: `netsolstores.com`).

Comment: Tweak Gordon's answer until it's returning the rows you want to delete (good to be sure when you're deleting lots of rows). Then tweak it to only return the ids of the rows you want to delete. Then do `delete from t where id in (/*Select statement here*/)`.